# Windows service does not work outside office environment

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-services, socketexception

I have developed my own Windows service on my work laptop. It is installed on `tcp` on local host on the port `555`. The service can be easily started and stopped from the office whether I am connected via `LAN` or `Wifi`.

Once the service is installed it will look for some jobs it has to do from an `Sqlite` database which, as you know, works without a connection and does not require a server.

As soon as I take my laptop home the service becomes unavailable. My program generates a `SocketException` that says

> No such host is known

And the service is unable to start.

So I spent half a working day to check my program for errors. Eventually I came back to the office to see the service is back to work without me having changed a thing. To make sure, I took my laptop to a coffee shop nearby and tested using their `Wifi`. It did not work there either.

I checked my IP on [What Is My IP?](http://www.whatismyip.com/) for any proxies but there are no proxies detected. But the mother company of my office that is giving us the internet resides in another city and What Is My IP also thinks that I am in that city. So I am currently only able to develop and test my service in the office environment. But that of course is a very bad thing since this Windows service should soon be installed on our customer servers. Any clues?

Comment: How is the connection to the server established? To 127.0.0.1 (thus, localhost) or to a local IP address (which usually has format 192.168.x.y, 172.16.x.y, or 10.x.y.z)?

Comment: @Sjips it is `127.0.0.1` on port `555`.

Comment: Very strange, because 127.0.0.1, localhost, always exist. `SocketException: No such host is known` for localhost... And pinging 127.0.0.1? If you cannot ping it, you're TCP stack could be screwed up.

Comment: @Sjips strange indeed. Yes I can ping `127.0.0.1` easily.

Comment: Are you sure there are NO other connections in your service? Use a sniffer tool to see how it behaves on the network when you are in your office. That might explain your issue. Identify the code line that fails. It might not be the one you are assuming. Also can the IP be blocked in your local firewall? You know, corporate policies being enforced on clients not connected to their network.

Comment: You can verify with `netstat -a -o` which ports are opened and where is listened to (enter this command in a CMD window). The PID is the process ID. If you are in the office, you can see what is which connecting (or is connected) with port 555.